# Hide table records temporarily in rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to hide some of the records of the statement temporarily with updated balance.

Please refer the screen-shot for better understanding as shown below;

[image: screenshot.png]

What I want is, when I clicked the hide button, it should hide the row completely and the balance must be carried forward and When **Show all** is clicked it must show all the records.

I have created hidden field in the table and written the hide_xvaziri method in the controller but confused with the hide button_to function in order to have, get '/xvaziri/:id/hide', to: 'xvaziris#hide_xvaziri'

20160729062246_add_hidden_to_xvaziris.rb

```
class AddHiddenToXvaziris < ActiveRecord::Migration

    def change
        add_column :xvaziris, :hidden, :boolean, :default => false  
    end

end
```

xvaziris_controller.rb

```
class XvazirisController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_xvaziri, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


    def index
        @xvaziris = Xvaziri.find_by hidden: false
        @xvaziris = Xvaziri.search(params[:search])

        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
            format.html 
        end 
    end

    def import
        Xvaziri.import(params[:file])
        redirect_to xvaziris_url, notice: "Xvaziris imported."
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @xvaziri = Xvaziri.new
    end

    def create
        @xvaziri = Xvaziri.new(xvaziri)
        if
            @xvaziri.save
            flash[:notice] = 'Xvaziri Created'
            redirect_to @xvaziri
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @xvaziri.update(xvaziri)
            flash[:notice] = 'Xvaziri Updated'
            redirect_to @xvaziri
        else
            render 'edit'
        end

    end

    def destroy
        @xvaziri.destroy
        flash[:notice] = 'Xvaziri was successfully destroyed.'
        redirect_to xvaziris_url    
    end

    def hide_xvaziri
        @xvaziri = Xvaziri.find(params[:id])
        @xvaziri.hidden = true
        flash[:notice] = 'Xvaziri was successfully hidden.'
        redirect_to xvaziris_url    
    end

    def reset_filter
        xvaziris = Xvaziri.all
        xvaziris.each do |xvaziri|
            xvaziri.hidden = false
        end
        redirect_to xvaziris_url
    end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_xvaziri
        @xvaziri = Xvaziri.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def xvaziri
        params.require(:xvaziri).permit(:date, :description, :amount, :discount, :paid)
    end

end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

            <div class="table-responsive myTable">

                <table id = "kola" class="table listing text-center">
                    <thead>
                    <tr class="tr-head">
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td>Amount</td>
                        <td>Discount</td>
                        <td>Paid</td>
                        <td>Balance</td>
                        <td>Button</td>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>              
                        <%= render @xvaziris %>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


<%= link_to "Show all", xvaziri_resetfilter_path %>
```

_xvaziri.html.erb

```
<tr   class="tr-<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">

    <td class="col-3"><%= span_with_possibly_red_color xvaziri.description %></td>


    <td class="col-1"><%= number_with_precision(xvaziri.amount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

    <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(xvaziri.discount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

    <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(xvaziri.paid, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>


    <% @balance += xvaziri.amount.to_f - xvaziri.discount.to_f - xvaziri.paid.to_f %>

    <% color = @balance >= 0 ? "pos" : "neg" %>

    <td class="col-1 <%= color %>"><%= number_with_precision(@balance.abs, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

    <td class="col-1"><%= button_to "Hide", '#', :method => "get" %></td>

</tr>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


    root 'xvaziris#index'

    resources :xvaziris do 
        collection { post :import }
    end

    get '/xvaziri/:id/hide', to: 'xvaziris#hide_xvaziri'

    get '/xvaziri/resetfilter', to: 'xvaziris#reset_filter'

end
```

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you trying to do this just with rails?

What you want is hide/show elements in the front-end.

The better way is using javascript/jquery

Here you have a lot of examples:

http://www.randomsnippets.com/2011/04/10/how-to-hide-show-or-toggle-your-div-with-jquery/

and here you can take a look of the jquery documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will I be able to retrieve the  balance after hiding the rows with jquery?

Comment: You need to implemente an ajax call. When you click the "hide" button. You will be altering the total of the balance too.

So, in your method (the one who calculate the amount), every time you click the "hide" option. You will be implementing an ajax call and using the method that "hides" the quantity of the row.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to call the ajax on hide buttons in my partial.

Comment: Mr.Carlos Orellana, hope you are right it can be done with ajax and if you don't mind it need your kind attention in order to solve my issue.